# Running QuickBooks in a XenApp Environment

Tags: citrix, xenapp, quickbooks

Just curious if people recommend running QuickBooks on the regular Citrix servers or if it's best to keep a separate server in the farm specifically for QuickBooks.

Answer (score 1):

We have been running Quickbooks on Xenapp for a while now.  We do keep the QB separate from other Apps.  We have seen numerous issues with QB on Citrix as Intuit does not support Quickbooks running on Xenapp.

Also, permission has to be changed in registry and in Program files folder where intuit is installed and also in Intuit's Application data directory so non-administrators can run the application.

I would keep it separate.